# GetX microservice with FloatingActionButton + What's a good choice? GetX or Flutter BLoC?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc, flutter-getx

Anyone here have used GetX Dialog Component inside of FloatingActionButton (FAB) in Flutter?

i have tried it. but, i still got error when implemented in build debug. can you have to give me a good choice. what's a good choic GetX or Flutter BLoC? thank you if you give me your opinion.

Comment: Are you using `MaterialApp`or `GetMaterialApp`?

Comment: Now, i'm using MaterialApp @S.M.JAHANGIR

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the comment, you are currently using `MaterialApp`, In order to use GetX Dialog component, you have to use `GetMaterialApp`.

And as for your second question, although it's matter of tastes and opinions, I think GetX is a great choice.

Comment: hmm, i see. what is advantages or disadvantages when we use GetX between of flutter BLoC?

Comment: GetX is more concise, easy to use, less boilerplate, and offers various utility features. It's a micro-framework within flutter you can say.  The only thing that can be concerning is that some of its feature syntax go sideways than that of flutter.